# Static files apply on all pages except index.html and base.html

Tags: css, django, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

I have an issue with static files. I uploaded the code on pythonanywhere, it runs, and I correctly linked the static URLs in pyanywhere>web page. the problem is that my static does not load on the index and base.html but on the other pages (where I have base.html extend it applies). Can you give me some support, please?
[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJF96.png)

[python anywhere url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O9bd.png)

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "home/Tsh2Dns/businessplaner/static/" 
#i tried to give root from pythonanywhere. still same response
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                ]
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
]
```

folders:

[image: files structure]

[here is the base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np12V.png)
[base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxVBa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5txR.png)
landing page.

all the other pages have the same beginning with base extend.
I have to mention that on my local it works just fine, only on pythonanywhere this happen

Comment: Grab static file url from rendered page, open it manually in separate tab. What's the error message? After deployment do you run app with DEBUG=true or false?

Comment: there is no error. it just does not apply on base and  on the landing page (index). debug is false. all the other pages have extend from base and  the static css works, but it does not on base.

Comment: Sounds like css/html-only issue. Validate markup, check class names. Share related css, html code so community can help.

Comment: It may not be your issue, but your STATIC_ROOT is not a correct path. You need a / at the start of that path.

Comment: @DenisTosh did no read your reply carefully. In debug=false django is not supposed to serve static files at all. "Other pages" are currently running on cache I guess.